# Internal Driver error Read time out in TOMCAT

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

we are using eclipse galileo and tomcat 5.5. after building the application when we try to run tomcat we are getting the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vbp.portal.util.BenefedsContextListener.initStartupServices(BenefedsContextListener.java:247)
    at com.vbp.portal.util.BenefedsContextListener.contextInitialized(BenefedsContextListener.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: com.vbp.common.exception.VbpException: SQL Exception received while executing the strQuery in SELECT BILL SUMMARY LIST method : Internal driver error.(Read timed outException Id: common.sys.exceptionData: []; 
     --- > nested: java.sql.SQLException: Internal driver error.(Read timed out; 
             ==> Nexted stackTrace java.sql.SQLException: Internal driver error.(Read timed out
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:344)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.sendAndReceive(AS400JDBCConnection.java:1787)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonExecute(AS400JDBCStatement.java:583)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:871)
    at com.vbp.common.caching.VbpParameterLoader.refresh(VbpParameterLoader.java:87)
    at com.vbp.common.caching.VbpParameterLoader.initialize(VbpParameterLoader.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.vbp.portal.util.BenefedsContextListener.initStartupServices(BenefedsContextListener.java:247)
    at com.vbp.portal.util.BenefedsContextListener.contextInitialized(BenefedsContextListener.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

    at com.vbp.common.caching.VbpParameterLoader.refresh(VbpParameterLoader.java:163)
    at com.vbp.common.caching.VbpParameterLoader.initialize(VbpParameterLoader.java:57)
Repeatedly and server is not getting started.
```

Mainly this SQLEXCEPTION INTERNAL DRIVER ERROR READ TIME OUT is happening.
PLease help us in resolving this issue.
JDK is 1.6
We could able to connect to database using as400 and checked the connection too. it is working fine. but when we try to use the connection in eclipse through tomcat server th above error is coming.

Comment: I guess that there are firewall restrictions not allowing you in, but allowing the as400 in.

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 i s unsupported, has been for some time and has known security vulnerabilities that will not be fixed. It is time to upgrade.

Comment: We have checked the firewall settings also. there is no problem with the firewall. and upgraded to TOMCAT 6.0. still same issue.